# How to consume external webservice in sencha touch2

Tags: web-services, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch2 and i want to consume external web service in sencha touch2.I have written code for this cause, showing alert msg not working! in console giving error like this XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld?_dc=1336466078991&method=Helloworld&format=json.

> Origin http://localhost:49692 is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   app/view/Blog.js?_dc=1336466047687:27Response Status:- 0

please help me what is the problem. Thank you

Here's my code :-

```
   Ext.define("GS.view.Blog", {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'blog',
    config: {
        title: 'WebService',
        scrollable: true,       
        items: [
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Press Me',
            height: 40,
            width: 200,
            listeners: {
                tap: function () {
//                    alert("Hi Welcome To Sencha");
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://localhost/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld',
                        params: { method: 'Helloworld', format: 'json' },
                        success: function (response, request) {
                            alert('Working!')
                            alert(response.responseText)
                            console.log('Response:-' + response.responseText)
                        },
                        failure: function (response, request) {
                            alert('Not working!')
                            console.log('Response Status:- ' + response.status)
                        }
                   });
                }
            }
          }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
        Ext.data.JsonP.request({

                    url: 'http://localhost/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld',
                    params: { method: 'Helloworld', format: 'json' },
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('Working!')
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert('Not working!')
                        console.log(response);
                    }
               });
```

Comment: i have used same code what you sent.but am getting same error in console like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval function for convert plain text to JSON data.

```
var newObject=eval('('+response.responseText+')');
```

Comment: k.i am not able consume web service..even failure alert msg not coming...what is the pbm..

Comment: I can't understand your code.why you add store as item of navigation?can you explain your requeriment?

Comment: now i have changed my code as above. it showing alert msg not working, in console it is giving like this error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld?_dc=1336466078991&method=Helloworld&format=json. Origin http://localhost:49692 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
app/view/Blog.js?_dc=1336466047687:27Response Status:- 0

Comment: this error means your server has no autentication for ajax request to url server.you should use Ext.data.JsonP.request instade of Ext.Ajax.request.

Comment: Ya i replaced.in console now i am getting like this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined

Comment: Ext.data.JsonP.request({

                        url: 'http://localhost/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld',
                        params: { method: 'Helloworld', format: 'json' },
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert('Working!')
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert('Not working!')
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                   });

Comment: i am getting same error in console like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined. i have used same code what you sent.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I figured out the solution to your problem.

First, read this excellent article on [Cross-domain Ajax with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) by Nicholas C. Zakas. It clearly explains this Cross-domain Cross-Origin resource sharing problem.

So, In your case, you need to make an [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) request.

> JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a complement to the base JSON data
>   format, a usage pattern that allows a page to request and more
>   meaningfully use JSON from a server other than the primary server.
>
> `JSONP is an alternative to a more recent method called Cross-Origin
>   Resource Sharing`.

All you need to do is make an [`Ext.util.JSONP.request()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP-method-request) call like this,

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
     url: 'http://localhost/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld',
     params: { 
         method: 'Helloworld',
         format: 'json',
         callback: 'callback',
     },

     success: function (response) {
           alert('Working!')
           console.log(response);
     },
     failure: function (response) {
            alert('Not working!')
            console.log(response);
     }
});
```

and that should work now!

Comment: i have  used same code what you sent, still it giving error in console like this _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined_. Above code is not working, can you tel me what is the problem. thank you.

Comment: Usually, when the error is of the form `Cannot call method 'X' of undefined`, it means that whatever object you are attempting to call `X` from does not exist. So, make sure you'r including the necessary files required for `Ext.util.JSONP` request...

Comment: I didn't get clearly, already sencha touch they are providing all the necessary files. can you give me solution to this console error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined**. what is problem in coding.