# Get attribute data from xml using sencha touch 2

Tags: xml, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I'm experimenting on how to get data from servers while programming with Phonegap and Sencha touch2.

I'm trying to get some weather data from the Google Weather API.

I got a panel with a list which should show the day_of_week data for now. But I can't find how I get data from attributes. If you look at the xml at http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=zonhoven you can see that the day of week is represented as:

So I got the following code:

```
Ext.define('WeerBe.view.mainTabs.TestPage', {
extend : 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype : 'testPage2',

config : {
    title : 'Test Page2',
    iconCls : 'info',

    scrollable : true,

    items : [{
        xtype : 'list',
        itemTpl: '{day_of_week}',

        store : {
            autoLoad: true,

            fields : ['day_of_week'],


            proxy : {
                type : 'ajax',
                url : 'http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=zonhoven',
                reader : {
                    type : 'xml',
                    root : 'weather',
                    record: 'forecast_conditions'
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
})
```

The lists contains 4 records as it should but it doesn't show data because the day_of_week node itself is empty and the data is in the data attribute.

How do I get the attribute data?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and checked the console log.

Here's the error that is being thrown:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=zonhoven&_dc=1336560194441&page=1&start=0&limit=25.
>   Origin http://localhost.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The error is because you'r making an `ajax` request which has it's [Cross-domain cross-origin resource sharing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10496813/202375)

So, change the proxy type to `'jsonp'`

```
proxy : {
      type : 'jsonp',
      url : 'http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=zonhoven',
      ....
      ....
```

Comment: Strange, I wasn't getting this error before and now I do too.
However when I change ajax into jsonp, I get the following error in the console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Probably because it expects json and not XML

Comment: It doesn't matter. `jsonp` request only used for making requests for data cross domain